# Can I use RedGard on my shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

One day my wife was showering and some water starting coming out of a light fixture underneath the shower.  I opened it up and didn't see any leaking pipes, and determined it was around the gasket interface in the actual drain itself.

[image]

To address this, I have been using a layer of clear waterproof silicone on top of the black gasket part, and it has helped but after time the silicone degrades and comes off.  Can I instead apply one or two coats of [RedGard](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-RedGard-1-Gal-Waterproofing-and-Crack-Prevention-Membrane-LQWAF1/100169081) waterproof membrane on the gasket and surrounding areas? Does anyone see an issue with this?  Or another recommendation?

Comment: RedGuard is not a gasket material.   You could try some polyurethane caulk. That may last longer, but the best solution is to replace the drain.

Comment: How is the grate fastened to the drain?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find a replacement gasket. Using a search engine, I found a Fernco 2 inch shower gasket with very little effort. Don't remove the existing gasket, though, unless an in-hand replacement looks promising. The current gasket looks bedded down too far, where I expect that the gasket should shed water into the drain. If you install a replacement, try to avoid positioning it so low that there's a pool of standing water sitting on it after showers.